# dismissing modalViewController from UITabBarController issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller

so in my app delegate I am trying to present a modalViewController from a UITabBarController, by doing the following:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
LoginViewController* loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        loginViewController.delegate = self;
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];
        [loginViewController release];
```

and the delegate defined in the app delegate is:

```
- (void)userDidLogin:(LoginViewController *) loginViewController
{
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE CALLED, DISMISSING");
    [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Here's my LoginViewController:

```
protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate;

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <MBProgressHUDDelegate>
{


    id<LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id<LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate

- (void)userDidLogin:(LoginViewController *) loginViewController;

@end
```

The issue is that this `(userDidLogin:(LoginViewController *) loginViewController)` is never called... why is this?
I have called the following in my LoginViewController implementation and this is called

```
[self.delegate userDidLogin:self];
```

**UPDATE:**

I got the delegate called now. The issue now is that when I call [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] it doesn't dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: But a LoginViewController does show up?

Comment: try initializing it with an nib.

Comment: yes the LoginViewController does show up when I use presentModalViewController

Comment: the issue now is that the delegate function in my app delegate is never called... I have added <LoginViewControllerDelegate> in my app delegate.h

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code from LoginViewController, but within that class's code you need to add the following lines when you are ready to dismiss it (perhaps when the user clicks the "Login" button and the login is successful).

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userDidLogin:)])
     [delegate performSelector:@selector(userDidLogin:) withObject:self];
```

UPDATE:

I think I understand what the issue is here.  According to Apple's documentation, when you call presentModalViewController:animated: the method sets the value of the "modalViewController" property of UIViewController (in this case your UITabBar).  However that property only maintains a weak reference to the modalViewController.  That's important because you initialize the LoginViewController, pass it in to presentModalViewController:animated: and then you release it.  Since presentModalViewController:animated: is not retaining a strong reference to the LoginViewController, the UITTabBar is unable to dismiss it later on.  In fact I'm surprised what you have done is not resulting in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.  I suggest you remove the "[loginViewController release]" statement and instead release it after you call "[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]"

Comment: I just did a check if(delegate == nil) before calling [delegate userDidLogin:self] and it returns true.. but why? I assigned it already

Comment: okay..now one step further.. the delgate is called, but now when I call  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; it's not dismissing it. However if I try to dismiss it from the LoginViewController it self it works..

Comment: Please see the update to my original answer above.  I believe the issue is that you are releasing the LoginViewController too early.  You must dismiss use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: before you release the reference to the LoginViewController.